# Getting a subclass's static data

Tags: java, class, subclass

I have a class `Player`, that needs to get a `Location` class. Each location class extends `Location`, which has a method `get()` that returns a static instance.

If the character has a string referring to the name of the location extension class, how can I get the instance?

Character:

```
public class Player {
    public static Location getLocation() {
        try {
            //return location
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Location:

```
public class Location{
    protected static Location singleton;
    public static Location get() {
        return null;
    }
```

Location class:

```
public class Finleydale extends Location{
    public static Location get() {
        if (Finleydale.singleton == null) {
            Finleydale.singleton = new Finleydale();
        }
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

I have multiple location extensions, and I have the singleton in the location class, so all location extensions have it; and the singleton is static because there is only one version of the location.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Whew, thanks for that edit @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I'm not used to the posting.

Comment: I don't see an exception to be thrown, so what are you attempting to catch?

Comment: `How, from a string, can I get that instance.` It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish here but you can't truly "override" static methods but it looks like you are trying to do that?  Static means that all instances of that class will share the same field so having `static Location singleton` in your base class is very likely to cause serious issues - all subclasses will be sharing the same instance.

Comment: @Makoto Netbeans was giving me an error about it.

Comment: But *what* error?  If it's a RuntimeException, those aren't declared to be thrown and can crop up at (un)fortunate times during the lifecycle of your application.  In your code, you're not declaring anything to be thrown.  Sometimes, an IDE may whine about something, but it may not always be correct.

Comment: Guys, I figured it out, but my reputation is too low to answer my own question: I'll post it tomorrow. Thanks for everyone's thoughts and ideas.

Comment: 'I have a class "Character"': You shouldn't. Don't re-use class names from the JDK, especially ones from `java.lang.`

Comment: @EJP Sorry, I mis-wrote that, the class is actually called "Player"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the get() function's static modifier away and changed the Player class as shown.
 All you other guys, your input was great.

```
    String locationS; //Class name
    public static Location getLocation() {
        return ((Location) Class.forName(locationS).newInstance()).get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you declared the static field in the base class means you have only one reference in the entire program.  If you have more than one subclass, and each one assigns to it, then each one is assigning to *the same* (static) field in the `Location` base class.  I think you want a separate singleton in each subclass.

If you want to look up a particular location by key (say a string value), then I don't think the Singleton pattern is quite what you are looking for.  I would create a "location registry" class, something like this:

```
public class LocationRegistry
    {
    private static final Map<String, Location> registry;
    static
        {
        final Map<String, Location> _registry = new HashMap<>();
        _registry.put("Finleydale", new Finleydale());
        // ...
        registry = Collections.unmodifiablemap(_registry);
        }

    public static Location getLocation(final String id)
        {
        return registry.get(id);
        }
    }
```

Some notes:

- You could still use the Singleton pattern to populate the registry
- The classic Singleton pattern, as demonstrated in your question, is not thread-safe.  A correctly thread-safe version without unnecessary locking is very tricky, if not impossible.  A `static final` field resolves that problem nicely.
- It isn't necessary to have the registry explicitly reference each Location subclass.  You could have each location register itself.  The only trick is to have a mechanism that would load the locations so that they can register themselves.
- Are subclasses actually suitable for this use?  Do different locations have different behaviors or just different data (ie name)?  If the latter, then I would just use a single Location class and a single factory, such as the static initializer above, to create each location.

Comment: Good idea, I'll think it over and tell you what I think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something about your object model seems wrong.  Why not have an interface `Locatable` with a `getLocation()` method on it, and implementers of the interface can return their respective locations.  A singleton `Location` just seems conceptually wrong.

```
interface Locatable { 
   Location getLocation();
}

class FinleyLand implements Locatable { 
    @Override
    Location getLocation() { 
       //whatever it takes to get you there...
    }     
}
```

Comment: There are also other methods in the location class, I just omitted them as they are not directly relate-able.

Comment: OK - extract them out into an interface.  If you aren't programming against interfaces, your object model tends to be more brittle.

Comment: What do you mean by "against interfaces"

Comment: Sorry - that was poorly worded.  What I meant was, if you can extract out the behavioral patterns in your program, you can create much more re-usable, re-factorable code, that hides ugly details.  Read Effective Java by Josh Bloch to see what I'm suggesting.